# A bug of Google Chrome when dragging the bookmark to the bookmark bar?

Tags: google-chrome

The question is: why there are many times when I drag the bookmark icon from the URL bar (the address bar) on Google Chrome, to the bookmark bar to add to my bookmarks, a region appears with a few URLs listed and cover up the bookmark bar, making it impossible to add to the bookmark bar.

Isn't this a bug?  How to solve it / overcome it?

P.S. This question may serve as both the question and answer.  I probably will add the answer below to follow the Q&A format on this site.

Answer (score 0):

After trial-and-errors, this is one solution:

after clicking on the bookmark icon, **hold the icon for a few seconds (hold the click), and then drag to your bookmark bar down below.**  This way, you will be able to add to your bookmarks.

P.S. I wonder why, when I am interviewed at Google as a programmer, they want perfect answers within 10 minutes, while this simple thing that have been disturbing me, happened for at least 2 years, and nobody cared, nobody fixed it.  And meanwhile, just keep on asking for perfect solutions at the interviews within that 10 minutes.